# Garlic butter sauce

Tags: sauce, butter, garlic

My family loves pasta with butter,garlic,and black olives topped with Parmesan but now I'm in a home with a gas stove and it causes the butter to clump to pasta and no longer is like a sauce stirred in pasta how do I get this to stop from clumping and being a butter sauce again

Comment: Welcome! Can you add some more details about the recipe and your cooking methods?

Answer (score 1):

1.When cooking the pasta, keep some of the water before draining them.
2. When mixing in the ingredients, add a little bit of the water, so that the ingredients make a sauce instead of just cloying together.

For step 2, you need to take your time; toss the ingredients and the pasta together for a couple of minutes.

You need to use a hot pan to mix the ingredients; if you use a cold pan or bowl, then the butter will harden and clump up.